# SDL_GetVideoSurface() equivalent function in SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm remaking a pong game, which I did in SDL 1.2, but in SDL 1.2, I had a function `SDL_GetVideoSurface()`, to take the surface of the screen (or I'm wrong about that?), however...

A little example in how I've used the function in my game(SDL 1.2)

```
void paddle::show() 
{
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, SDL_GetVideoSurface(), &box);
}
```

I want to know if there is an equivalent function to `SDL_GetVideoSurface()` in SDL 2.0, I've searched, but found nothing. And if it didn't exists, how can I blit a surface? The surface is my paddle in the pong game.

Comment: You might be looking for [SDL_GetWindowSurface()](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface?highlight=%28\bCategoryVideo\b%29|%28CategoryEnum%29|%28CategoryStruct%29)

Comment: may be, but i need a pointer to the main window, and the main window is in main.cpp, i did one class in the paddle.cpp. How can i do for the SDL_Window *window, be visible? Create it in one class?

Comment: That function returns a pointer to a `SDL_Surface*`. I've used the SDL 1* version, and it appears to be the same from the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try, but first, i have to make the main window of my game visible to all .cpp archives in my project, so what is the recommend?

Comment: SDL 1.2 had exactly one 'screen' surface - there was no way to create more. This is a sure flaw that was addressed in SDL 1.3 (later becoming 2.0) with completely abandoning old windowing API and introducing 'windows' and 'renderers'. So, by design, there is no 'default' or 'main' window in terms of SDL. Basically you could create a function that returns surface that you need, taking it from e.g. static variable assigned on window creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a equivalent function to SDL_GetVideoSurface() in SDL 2.0

There isn't one.

If you're feeling insane you *could* iterate over the entire `Uint32` range and use [`SDL_GetWindowFromID()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowFromID) to search for the window(s) you created.

Keeping track of the `SDL_Window*`s returned by `SDL_CreateWindow()` like keltar suggested is the better option.

Answer (score -1):

i try to change `SDL_GetVideoSurface` to use `SDL_GetWindowSurface`.

Example.

```
x == SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->w
```

see SDL2 for more information : 
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface